# Does $u v^T + v u^T$ have exactly one positive and one negative eigenvalue when $u \not \propto v$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does $u v^T + v u^T$ have exactly one positive and one negative eigenvalue when $u \not \propto v$?

$u$ and $v$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: if u=-v it doesn't work.  if u,v are orthogonal it definitely works.  if they aren't orthogonal, i haven't solved for the eigenvectors, but i suspect there is some simple formula for them that should finish it.

Comment: @Jack: sorry i screwed up the question a bit, I'll change it.

Comment: Without loss of generality, you can take $u$ to be $(1, 0, ..., 0)^T$.

Comment: Another WLOG is n=2 since the subspace spanned by u and v is invariant. so v=[a,b] but I haven't had a chance to finish.

Comment: When n=2, char poly is negative at x=0 and positive at the ends, so one pos and one neg root.  Seems long and ugly compared to the orthogonal case where u+v and u-v are the eigenvectors and this is basically "symmetric and anti-symmetric parts".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I presume that $u$, $v$ are nonzero. By absorbing the length of $u$ into $v$, we may assume WLOG that $\|u\|=1$. Let $v=\alpha u + \beta w$ for some unit vector $w\perp u$. Note that $\beta\not=0$ because $u \not \propto v$. Also, $uv^\top+vu^\top = 2\alpha uu^\top+\beta uw^\top+\beta wu^\top$. Hence
$$
uv^\top+vu^\top \sim
\begin{pmatrix}
2\alpha&\beta\\
\beta&0
\end{pmatrix}\oplus0_{n-2}
$$
and the result follows immediately.

Comment: Looks good.  This is what I was trying to outline above, but you made it look simple and smooth.  I especially like the simple fix for non-orthogonal v. In case anyone misses the last tilde: Choose a basis {u,w} and extend it with things perpendicular to both u and w, and then uvt+vut has the simple form given by user1551.