# How to calculate the eigenvalue of the following general matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the $n\times n$ matrix $Z$ with $(i,j)$-element defined by $Z_{i,j}=i+j$. How to calculate the eigenvalue of $Z.$?

I have used Matlab to calculate it. I find no matter how bigger n is, there are always two nonzero eigenvalues. But how to get the formula for eigenvalues of $Z$?

Comment: See this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261077/symmetric-matrix-eigenvalues/1261581#1261581